# Provide update to user

Tags: java

I am working in a java application, in which all the users will get automatic update when the user is connected to internet. I am trying a simple logic like this:

1. My application will search for the validity of the user.
2. If the user is valid a folder will be downloaded from http://example.com/update/
3. The downloaded folder will be stored somewhere in disk.
4. My project folder's dist folder will be replaced with the new downloaded file.

   I am stumbled in the No. 4.
   OS does not allow me to replace in-use files.
   Is there any other solution, so that I can provide updates to my users.?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to write a "boot application" that checks if there are updates available and update the software file and then launch the real application.

Comment: I don't understand why some people downvote without providing an argument on why the idea is not useful. In my opinion having a launcher that can operate on the files of the real app before launching it, is valid scenario. Because you can't replace the files while they are in use, you could download them to a temp folder, then execute the launcher again and exis. The "boot app / launcher" would replace the old files with the new one, and launch the application

Comment: I work for a big application and between our client/server tu provide automatic update we use this method and work ok. For the downvote i think that person have a better idea. So i wait his answer.....